# Draw LINE_STRIP with Unity

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine

For a new project I am thinking about whether to use OpenGL or Unity3d. I have a bit of experience with OpenGL, but I am completely new to Unity. I already read through the Unity documentation and tutorials on the Unity Website. However, I could not find a way to draw a simple Line-Strip with Unity.

In the following example (C#, OpenGL/SharpGL) I draw a round trajectory from a predifined point to an obstacle, which can be imagined as a divided circle with midpoint *[cx,cy]* and radius *r*. The position (x-y coordinates) of the obstacle is given by *obst_x* and *obst_y*.

**Question 1:** How could I do the same with Unity?

**Question 2:** In my new project, I will have to draw quite a lot of such geometric primitives. Does it make any sense to use Unity for those things?

```
void drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, const float obst_x, const float obst_y) 
{
    float theta = 0.0f, pos_x, pos_y, dist;
    const float delta = 0.1;

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

    while (theta < 180) 
    { 
        theta += delta;                 //get the current angle 

        float x = r * cosf(theta);      //calculate the x component 
        float y = r * sinf(theta);      //calculate the y component 

        pos_x = x + cx;                 //calculate current x position
        pos_y = y + cy;                 //calculate current y position

        //calculate distance from current vertex to obstacle
        dist = sqrt(pow(pos_x - obst_x) + pow(pos_y - obst_y));

        //check if current vertex intersects with obstacle
        if dist <= 0
        {
            break;                      //stop drawing circle
        }
        else
        {
            glVertex2f(pos_x, pos_y);   //draw vertex
        }
    }

    glEnd(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## How to draw line strip

[SetIndices](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.SetIndices.html) method of Mesh class allows you to chose [MeshTopology](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshTopology.html). What you need is  `MeshTopology.LineStrip`.

## How to draw lines

You can also use [LineRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html) component to draw lines. I would strongly recommend you to consider it as an option.

## Do you need to use Unity 3D?

It's up to you :)

## Side notes

Usage of `glBegin`, `glEnd` and `glVertex` functions is known as immediate mode, and is considered as deprecated nowadays (because of performance problems).